# How to wedge in, or extrude triangularly?

Tags: modeling, extrude

Or how to go from this [image: cube]

to this

[image: cube with missing wedge]

I know it can be done with the knife or by extruding an edge and then delete faces and recreate them, but both solutions seem too complicated for a single thing that is so often needed. The same applies for creating a wedge out, though that is a bit easier.

Comment: Try the Boolean Modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select top edge, the one where you'd like to add one more.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to activate *Rip Fill* tool (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> > *Rip Fill* in menu). The edge will get ripped out, but connected to the rest of geometry at the same time.
3. To grab it accordingly to the geometry, press <kbd>G</kbd> immediately after ripping to activate *Edge Slide* tool. The new edge will be moved along the existing edges.
4. If you *really* would like to get rid of edges going down to the original loop cut, you can dissolve them. Do note though that this will result in an Ngon, which can be treated not as you expect it to be (and hence you may want to rip fill *both* top and bottom edges using stated method; as a result the new edge will be a part of new loopcut).

   [image: ripping edge GIF]

Comment: Accepted answer because it can do [this](http://play.qwazix.com/shared/Screenshot%20from%202016-05-30%2014-27-10.png) without the extra faces that a loop cut would create outside the intended region.

Answer (score 4):

You can push your top face down, add a loop cut, then extrude one face up. Then, you can simply drag the remaining edge to the same height.

[image]

You can also skip the first step, and simply add a loopcut. Select the face on the right, press extrude, and <kbd>LMB</kbd>. Then, pull up that face and the other edge.

[image]

This one is a little bit tricky, but uses the same method. Add a loopcut, Select the face on the left, press extrude, then click. Then, with the vertex selection mode active, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to select evreything but the vertices connected to that face. Then, deselect all vertices except for the two in the middle. You can now move them down. DO note that you may want to also press <kbd>W</kbd> - Remove doubles, as this method will have two vertices in the same spot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the same final shape is

1. subdivide only the upper face

[image]

2. then subdivide one of the new half faces

[image]

3. then grab the newest edge and grab it down Z

[image]

4. then activate snap tools to edges

[image]

5. and grab the same edge to match Y of the upper edge

[image]

6. you'll end up with this

[image]

It's not extruding, but it gets the job done and gives you as few faces as possible, thanks to ngons.